# Including files in building apk application in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

How to add files and folders to the apk file when building it in unity.

What I need is to have some files and a folder to be present in the parent directory of the application ( android/data/com.company.product/files) after installing it on Android.

Comment: afaik you can ONLY copy from streaming assets folder into android persist path.

Comment: I did just that: I copy my files to StreamingAssets folder and I attach a script just as they said in this link: "https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html" but "persistentDataPath" still empty.

Comment: that might be an access violation issue. make sure you gave  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions in manifest

Comment: I add this line to the Androidmainfest file: " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> " but I got the same result

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for copying files from streaming assets into android persist path:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
public static class FileManager
{
    public static string RereadFile(string fileName)
    {  //copies and unpacks file from apk to persistentDataPath where it can be accessed
        string destinationPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string sourcePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName);
#else
        string sourcePath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName;
#endif

        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", sourcePath,  File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(sourcePath), File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(destinationPath)));

        //copy whatsoever

        //if DB does not exist in persistent data folder (folder "Documents" on iOS) or source DB is newer then copy it
        //if (!File.Exists(destinationPath) || (File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(sourcePath) > File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(destinationPath)))
        {
            if (sourcePath.Contains("://"))
            {
                // Android  
                WWW www = new WWW(sourcePath);
                while (!www.isDone) {; }                // Wait for download to complete - not pretty at all but easy hack for now 
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, www.bytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("ERROR: the file DB named " + fileName + " doesn't exist in the StreamingAssets Folder, please copy it there.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Mac, Windows, Iphone                
                //validate the existens of the DB in the original folder (folder "streamingAssets")
                if (File.Exists(sourcePath))
                {
                    //copy file - alle systems except Android
                    File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("ERROR: the file DB named " + fileName + " doesn't exist in the StreamingAssets Folder, please copy it there.");
                }
            }
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(destinationPath);
        var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();


        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It works on pc and it copies all files, but when try it on Samsung S4 it doesn't.

Comment: try debug.log source and destination paths and read them in logcat. maybe an exception occurs on device. I've been using this piece of code for almost a year now and I never had any problem on any device

Comment: and make sure you included the extension

Comment: DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/jar:file:/data/app/com.ScryptechTest.AirFlow-2.apk!/assets' not found. This is the error

Comment: make sure you get this line right: `"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName` where `filename` is exact same file name in streaming assets with its file extension (I don't know about case sensitivity but use the same just in case)

Comment: This solution works 100% guaranteed. If it doesn't then it's another issue you should track down.

Comment: I am getting file names dynamically, and the problem is not with it because it works perfect when I tried it with unity on pc

Comment: The error indicates that the url is not valid (it starts with a slash) make sure you get that right

Comment: but the only line that I use this url is the one you write in your code: " string sourcePath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + fileName; "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134197/discussion-between-bilal1409-and-bijan).