# Accessing a specific location on an Android device through code

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am serializing/deserializing files into the path that is returned from Application.persistentDataPath to save/load levels created by the player and it works flawlessly. However, when I try to access the same path via Directory.GetFiles() I get returned a value of 0.

Here is how I am saving:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\" + name + ".LevelData", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, level);
}
```

The reason I am trying to access this location is so that I can have a menu pop up that asks the player which level they want to load, and then it would show every level they have created so that they can pick it and edit it.

This returns a string array of size zero:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath, "*LevelData", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Also, after debugging the path that is returned from Application.persistentDataPath I noticed that the path it returns doesn't actually exist on my mobile device. It has some weird behaviours though, as if I try to create the folder that would complete that path, my device simply wont let me, but if I try to name the folder anything else it works just fine.

Is there a different library that I need in order to access files on an Android device from Unity? Directory.GetFiles() works fine when working on Windows.

Comment: did you include the write permission in android manifest?

Comment: I didn't, but I was under the assumption that because the serialization/loading is working (even after closing/reopening the app) that the files were successfully being created. Do you think I need the write permission for Directory.GetFiles?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41857019/366064 and yes you need permission

Comment: Windows uses backslashes but android uses forward slashes, check if this is your problem.

Comment: @Bijan That post isn't what I need. My levels correctly save and load on the device, but what I need to be able to do is get a collection of all the files in that location so that I can print them out to the user. I also went ahead and added the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file and put it in Assets/Plugins/Android/. I'm not 100% sure if that is the right way to do it, so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting fed up with this, so I decided an alternate route.

Since I was able to serialize/deserialize files, I just serialized a List that I am going to keep up to date with the levels currently in the system. Every time a new level is added, the name is added to the list and serialized. Whenever a level is removed, the name is removed from the list and serialized. Whenever the user goes to load a level, this list is populated into the dropdown so the player can pick which level they want to load.

Anyways, thanks for the help everyone!